# [SOLVED] How do I control 2 dynamixel motors simultaneously using a service?

Tags: ros, dynamixel, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could only send for one motor at a time...

```
dynamixel_workbench_msgs::DynamixelCommand srv;

srv.request.id = // 2 ids;
srv.request.addr_name = “Goal_Position";
srv.request.value = // 2 values;


if (goal_dynamixel_command_client_.call(srv))
{
  return srv.response.comm_result;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387762/%5Bsolved%5D-how-do-i-control-2-dynamixel-motors-simultaneously-using-a-service?/) by [danielguilbert](https://answers.ros.org/users/86035/danielguilbert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All I did was to edit the service file (by duplicating the 3 arguments) and dynamixel_workbench_controllers.cpp under function dynamixelCommadMsgCallback (using a loop). Next, remove the build and devel folders, and build your packages all over again.

---

Originally posted by [danielguilbert](https://answers.ros.org/users/86035/danielguilbert/) with karma: 16 on 2021-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0